# Problem no such file or directory on Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am creating an image in Docker and I get the following error:

> ADD failed: stat
> /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder985672265/startboostrap-freelancer-master:
> no such file or directory

File:

```
FROM centos

RUN yum install httpd -y

ADD startboostrap-freelancer-master /var/www/html

CMD apachectl -DFOREGROUND
```

Instruction used to create the image:

```
docker build -f dockerfile3 --tag apache .
```

[Image with the Problem and the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHpjQ.png)

Comment: Do you have startboostrap-freelancer-master in ~/docker-images?

Answer (score 0):

`startboostrap-freelancer-master`  isn't available in the current directory from where you are creating the image.

This file must be present inside `~/docker-images/` folder.